# Well-Known Text format (WKT) country dataset

Tags: geospatial

Is there a dataset free online that I can download to get the country coordinates (polygons) in WKT format?

I cannot find it anywhere. I would like a dataset that includes both the country name and the polygons (no multipolygons) of the same country in WKT format. Also, I would like that the dataset ignores the islands (for example I would like only the mainland of France and not the islands). Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can find them in another format, you can use gdal/ogr tools to convert to WKT. Removing the islands is trickier. Are you saying you want the largest polygon for each nation, or want to remove everything Greenland sized or smaller, unless it constitutes the nation's largest polygon?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have the dataset for Europe (only the polygons), but for example, for France, Greece and Italy I have not the islands. What I want is to merge this dataset with another one that includes the countries name. Now I have only the polygons, and this complicates analysis.

Comment: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/ might have the data you need, as would https://gadm.org/data.html

Answer (score 0):

https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries#resource-countries

These are Geojson values. You can either convert them online in WKT or use as is. I have used and verified this. Pretty awesome.

Cheers!!